# Insert parameter depending on boolean value

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Is it possible to insert a parameter in a function depending on a boolean value?

For example, I have this piece of code:

```
Math.min(boolA ? doubleValueA, boolB ? doubleValueB);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect e.g. if boolA=false?

Comment: What will be the parameter if `boolA` is false, for instance?

Comment: I don't need to worry about all of the boolean values being false. If one of the values is false, the corresponding double value shouldn't be a paramter in the function.

Comment: @EthanM: Except for the fact the example you are using (`Math.min`) takes exactly two parameters.  You can't selectively leave out parameters in this case.

Comment: @mellamokb I see. I was under the misconception that the Math.min function could have 'infinite' parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default value (such as Double.MAX_VALUE) if `boolA` or `boolB` is false:

```
Math.min(
    (boolA) ? doubleValueA : Double.MAX_VALUE,
    (boolB) ? doubleValueB : Double.MAX_VALUE
);
```

**Edit**

If you have a list of variables that you want to find the minimum, but only if the corresponding boolean variable is set, load the list into  an array and find the minimum:

```
ArrayList<Double> myArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
if (boolA) myArray.add(doubleValueA);
if (boolB) myArray.add(doubleValueB);
// etc

double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE; // start with largest possible value
// loop through and replace with any smaller values
for (double val : myArray)
    if (val < minValue) minValue = val;
// val now contains the smallest value
```

**Edit 2**

This can also be applied in general to other functions.  Selectively add your parameters to an array, and pass the array to the function.  If you have control over the function definition, you can use [variable arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) to make it simpler.

```
public double MyMin(double... myArray) {
    double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE; // start with largest possible value
    // loop through and replace with any smaller values
    for (double val : myArray)
        if (val < minValue) minValue = val;
    // val now contains the smallest value
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your first proposition is somehow what I am looking for.
The ArrayList implementation looks promising, might use it for other projects.

Answer (score 1):

java does not have operator like

```
boolA ? doubleValueA
```

but supports [ternary operator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
boolA ? doubleValueA : defaultValue
```

it means that if `boolA` is true, then use `doubleValueA` otherwise use `defaultValue`. Otherwise

```
Math.min(boolA ? doubleValueA, boolB ? doubleValueB);
```

would be pointless if `boolA` is false (except for special processing and going with `null` in this case, but Java does not)

altogether, you should change to

```
Math.min(boolA ? doubleValueA : defaultA, boolB ? doubleValueB : defaultB);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ternary operator, you need a false condition.  Say you want to make sure that if boolA is false then doubleValueB will be min while if boolB is false doubleValueA will be min.  You could make the other condition be the max integer and then this will be the case.

Of course if both boolA and boolB are false then your value will be the max integer value.  If that can ever happen, then you'll need additional code to handle it.

```
Math.min(boolA ? doubleValueA : Integer.MAX_VALUE, boolB ? doubleValueB : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Note that [Math.min(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) does not take varargs.  If you want to use a variable-length argument list as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) you'll need your own min function with varargs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(boolA && boolB) {
    Math.min(doubleA, doubleB);
} else if(boolA) {
    doubleA;
} else if(boolB) {
    doubleB;
} else {
    ????
}
```

Comment: True, though I initially wanted a more compact way for writing it. This was what I started off with. Thanks though!